# What is this Google URL

Tags: html, url, web

I've recently written a script that monitors all web traffic on my site, pages visited and http referees etc.  the only thing is this URL pops up quite a lot:

```
http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=CpEvvFIUuU-HsL-KLsQeToYAQ0p6OgwTSx7TDZZCY14MBCAAQAVDi_eSK-v____8BYMmG_4fwo-wSyAEBqgQfT9AXzXKHZOapkrGJKMmlEyCHmzHyLx_B7YlQXndIb7oFEwjb7J2xiai9AhVkTjIKHdpMAFPKBQCAB6LT4CuQBwM&ei=FIUuU9uSLOScyQHamYGYBQ&sig=AOD64_22JDmj354Hn
```

But when I goto it it is just blank.  Any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this post : http://clicky.com/forums/?id=6591

It seems to be something google uses to track clicks on ads, with aclk bieng short of ad click.

And it returns a blank page as the link throws a bad request error, when accessed directly. Which essentially means no page has been loaded. (check console).

[image]

Comment: Right, thank you I couldn't check console as I'm on my ipad.  But that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of obfuscation techniques called "Secure Search" implemented by Google a couple of years ago to prevent traffic analysis tools from gathering Keyword/User data due to privacy concerns.

It is caused by the user being logged in with their Google account when they click through to your website, therefore the URL is unique to each user session and this is why it returns a blank page.

In Google Analytics this results in `(not provided)` keyword data accounting for around 80% to 90% of all referrals.

More info here: 
http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2296351/Goodbye-Keyword-Data-Google-Moves-Entirely-to-Secure-Search